# Updating SQL table w/CTE and multiple results from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm using the following query; but it's not working. The challenge is that e.Value can return multiple results per Document (and thus per Equipment) and I want to update Equipment.LastCheck with the most recent e.Value (hence the ORDER BY d.CreatedDate).

No matter what I try, the Equipment.LastCheck isn't updated. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT eq.LastCheck,
                e.Value                                         AS Result,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.CreatedDate DESC) AS Rn
         FROM   Equipment eq
                INNER JOIN Documents d
                  ON d.EquipmentId = eq.EquipmentId
                INNER JOIN Elements e
                  ON e.ElementId = d.ElementId
         WHERE  e.Name = 'CheckDate'
                AND e.Value IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE cte
SET    LastCheck = Result;
```

Comment: You're missing `WHERE Rn = 1`

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think there should be any "WHERE Rn=1" since Rn will be a serial number in the result from the subquery. If I'd place Rn=1 in there, it would only update the first result from the subquery.

Comment: Ah you're missing a `PARTITION BY eq.EquipmentId` as well for that to work. Though I wouldn't do it like that.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm open to all suggestions, if you have a better method to do this, please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach without using CTE:

```
UPDATE eq
SET eq.LastCheck = e.Value
FROM Equipment eq
  INNER JOIN Documents d ON d.EquipmentID = eq.EquipmentID
  INNER JOIN Elements e ON e.ElementID = d.ElementID
WHERE d.EquipmentID = eq.EquipmentID 
  AND e.Name = 'CheckDate'
  AND e.Value IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Documents d2
      INNER JOIN Elements e2 ON e2.ElementID = d2.ElementID 
    WHERE d2.CreatedDate > d.CreatedDate AND d2.EquipmentID = eq.EquipmentID
  )
```

The NOT EXISTS statement ensures that the Documents record with the most recent CreatedDate is returned.

---

**UPDATE:**
Using CTE is more efficient. The full query to do what you want is below, incorporating PARTITION BY eq.EquipmentID and WHERE Rn = 1, as suggested from Martin Smith's comments.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  eq.LastCheck,
            e.Value AS Result,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY eq.EquipmentID 
                ORDER BY d.CreatedDate DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM Equipment eq
        INNER JOIN Documents d ON d.EquipmentId = eq.EquipmentId
        INNER JOIN Elements e ON e.ElementId = d.ElementId
    WHERE e.Name = 'CheckDate'
        AND e.Value IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET LastCheck = Result
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. There are 40K entries in the Equipment table, 100K+ entries in the Document and over 1MLN entries in Element table. In short: performance is important! Can you give me a good reason(s) why I would, or would not use CTE?

Comment: I don't really have a reason not to use CTE, this was just another approach. But when I looked at the performance, CTE did in fact perform better. See my updated answer with the complete query, incorporating Martin Smith's comments from above.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT eq.LastCheck,
                e.Value                                         AS Result,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.CreatedDate DESC) AS Rn
         FROM   Equipment eq
                INNER JOIN Documents d
                  ON d.EquipmentId = eq.EquipmentId
                INNER JOIN Elements e
                  ON e.ElementId = d.ElementId
         WHERE  e.Name = 'CheckDate'
                AND e.Value IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE cte
SET    LastCheck = Result
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: That was only a partial solution, see MartinSmith's comments on my original post